# HTML/CSS how to change <embed> element size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed a `html` file inside my website.

I am trying to embed a `chart` into the website, but I just can't make it, so that `chart` is fully displayed. Does anyone know how that works? I could not find anything on the web and i am not that good at programming yet.(after all i started my apprenticeship as a software developer 2 weeks ago.)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdnqo.png)
As you can see there is 2 scrollbars on the side, 1 for the chart and 1 for the page it's self. There also is a horizontal bar for the chart. I basically just want there to be 1 bar for the page it's self if you know what i mean
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6tpaemd/)

Comment: Please share your codes.

Comment: html: <div class="embedfile">
  <div class="lernzielkontrolle">
   <embed src="index.html" scale="tofit"></embed>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: css: .embedfile
{
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

.lernzielkontrolle embed
{
 width: 100%;

Comment: please add screenshot or website link so we understand what you mean by "so that chart is fully displayed."